# I want the average of the two biggest variables among the three variables n1, n2, n3. Can someone help me.

Tags: c++

I want the average of the two biggest variables among the three variables n1, n2, n3. Can someone help me. I ask the user to enter three notes will be stored in variables n1, n2, n3. then I want the program to return the average of the two biggest variables.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float ra[23], qte_alunos=0;
    float n1[29],n2[33],n3[33],op1[22],op2[22], fina[22];
    string nome[23], curso[23];

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++){

    cout << "digite RA: ";
    cin >> ra[i];
    cout << "digte nome: ";
    cin >> nome[i];
    cout << "digite curso: ";
    cin >> curso[i];
    cout << "digite N1: ";
    cin >> n1[i];
    cout << "digite N2: ";
    cin >> n2[i];
    cout << "digite N3: ";
    cin >> n3[i];

    if (n1[i] > n2[i] && n2[i] > n3[i]){
        n1[i] = op1[i];
        n2[i] = op2[i];
    }

    if (n2[i] > n3[i] && n3[i] > n1[i]){
        n2[i] = op1[i];
        n3[i] = op2[i];
    }

    if (n3[i] > n1[i] && n1[i] > n2[i]){
        n3[i] = op1[i];
        n1[i] = op2[i];
    }

    fina[i] = (op1[i]+op2[i])/2;

    if (fina[i] > 6 ){
        cout << "aprovado " << fina[i];
    }
    if (fina[i] > 4 && fina[i] < 5.9){
        cout << "exame " << fina[i];
    }

    if (fina[i] < 4){
        cout << "reprovado " << fina[i];
    }
    cout << "\n" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The posted code is completely different from the question in the title. What's up with that?

Comment: `I want the average of the two biggest variables among the three variables`: And what's so hard about that?

Comment: Can you put the 3 digits in an array, sort the array and take the last 2 and average them?

Comment: No, put 3 digits in 3 variables differences, and I want the average of the 2 biggest variables.

Comment: Hi,
Missing cases. for example : 

    if (n2[i] > n1[i] && n1[i] > n3[i]) ...

In addition it is preferable to use a wide inequality <=

And for example n2[i] = op1[i]; must be op1[i] = n2[i];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you right you want `(sum(a, b, c) - min(a, b, c)) / 2`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main (int argc, const char **argv) {
    double a = 1;
    double b = 2;
    double c = 3;
    double min = std::min({a, b, c});
    // double max = std::max({a, b, c});
    double sum = a + b + c;
    // double result = ((sum - min - max) + max) / 2;
    // which is:
    double result = (sum - min) / 2;
    std::cout << result << '\n';
}
```